# How to open simple html file in Orweb browser?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, html

I have installed Orweb(Android equiv of tor browser), Orweb doesn't appear to allow bookmarks only a homepage, no problem I'll just create a simple html page containing a list of links and set this as the homepage....

Via ES Explorer I tried setting the html file to open in Orweb using 'open as' but Orweb is not listed in the app list.

I tried opening the file in Orweb by pasting a direct link to the file in the address bar, but Orweb then insists on searching the web for the link string.

I tried setting Orweb as the default browser using 'default app manager' which seems to be accepted, but when I try to open the html file it still asks which app to use and again Orweb is not in the list of apps.

Ideas?